# "Invalid License Data. Reinstall is required" error when installing SharePoint 2013 after Sql Server 2012 on the same machine

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, visual-studio, sql-server

I've already installed SQL Server 2012 on my machine.  Then I tried to run the SharePoint 2013 Foundation installer but I received the following error before I even reached the splash screen menu:

[image: Invalid license data. Reinstall is required.]

I've already tried the [advice from a form posting stating that I should reinstall SQL Server 2012](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/2b39c4aa-2fe0-46a9-be56-dd123e13a268/problem-while-running-installation-of-sharepoint-foundation-2013?forum=sharepointadmin) but that did not work.

This server is a development machine so I would like to keep SQL Server and SharePoint on this 1 machine.  What should I do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I discovered that the problem comes from the program *Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Shell (Isolated) - ENU* that gets installed with SQL Server 2012.  After uninstalling that program and then running the SharePoint 2013 installer I am able to see the splash screen.

[image: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Shell (Isolated) - ENU]

**Warning** - This will prevent Sql Server Management Studio 2012 from working on that machine.

Comment: I wish I'd run across your post 24 hours of effort or so ago. No matter what I tried, SSMS 2012 kept giving me the license error when I tried to run it. I've gone so far as to manually delete ALL SQL Server related registry keys and program files[ x86] folders. I even run a repair-upgrade of Windows and got nowhere. Uninstalling VS 2010 shell fixed it though. One of these days I'm going to have to calculate all my lost time see how much I actually save or lose relying on MS products. Thanks for sharing!!!!

Comment: I'm glad that I could help.  It took me testing out a bunch of solutions that didn't work before I found this solution so I know how you feel.  Also, as a new StackOverflow user you want to put what you wrote as a comment to my answer and not as an answer itself.  And make sure to upvote good answers.

Comment: This also prevents SQL Server Management Studio 2014 from working...alas I was hoping it wouldn't.  You can download the shell [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=1366) if you've already uninstalled it.

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but maybe it will help future users.

Got the same problem on a PC with VS2013, SQL 2012, and Office 2013.

Solved the problem by opening a .sln-file with "Open with" and checked "Always use the selected program".

Answer (score 0):

I found the .hta file extension needed to be set back to Microsoft HTML Application Host instead of Visual Studio after I selected Visual Studio by mistake when running the Sharepoint install. Do this from the file association settings in the control panel.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error in my exercise SSAS Lesson 4 start, [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/lesson-4-2-defining-parent-attribute-properties-in-a-parent-child-hierarchy)
when I open a SSAS PROJECT FILE.
**Solution: right click project name, select Microsoft Visual Studio 2015, it works.**

reason:
My computer environment:
WINDOWS 2008r2
Sql 12.0.5000 (SQL server 2014)
MS vs2010, it comes something I don't know, maybe I installed it before
MS VS 2013 express web
MS VS 2015, this is a SSDT intallation, VS2015 Shell
so, if I double click the project name, it run use the VS2010, some issue can happen because compatibility.